# Main method error can't figure out how to fix

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods

Getting a main method error which is only affecting my retrieve salary method I'm not sure what to do to fix the issue I have added particular items but I can't get the error to go away. Is the only thing on my program that brings up an error and I am unable to continue. Image included of the only issues I'm encountering now

"Error: Main method not found in class, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application"

[Image included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cPpv.png)

```
public class finalproject {

public static class employeeCase {
       EMPLOYEE[] employees;
       int AMOUNT;
      
       employeeCase(){
           employees = new EMPLOYEE[100];
           AMOUNT = 0;
           
       }

private void loadEmployee() {
    
    
    String ID = null;
       
    int SALARY = 0;
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("How many employees do you want to load?: ");
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
        
        // Display parallel arrays
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Name: " + employees[i] + " " + "ID: " + ID + " " + "Salary: " + SALARY);
        
        sc.close();
    }

}
private int addEmployee() {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("How many employees do you want to enter?: ");
    AMOUNT = 0;
    AMOUNT = sc.nextInt();
    
    String Again1 = "no";
    
    String Fname;
    
    String ID;
       
    int SALARY = 0;
    
    do {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++) {
            
    
     
    System.out.printf("Enter employee's first name: ");
    Fname = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Enter employee ID (5 digits): ");
    ID = sc.next();
    System.out.printf("Enter employee salary: ");
    SALARY = sc.nextInt();
    
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    
    this.employees[this.AMOUNT] = new EMPLOYEE(Fname, ID, SALARY);
    this.AMOUNT++;
    
    sc.close();
    
        }   } while (Again1.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
    return SALARY;
    
}

private void displayEmployee() {

    

    for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++){
    
        // Display parallel arrays
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println(this.employees[i]);
        
    }

}

private void retrieveSpecific() {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("Enter employee ID: ");
    String id = sc.next();
    
    //Search for ID in all the stored employees
       for(int i=0; i<this.AMOUNT; i++) {
           
       
           if(id.contentEquals(this.employees[i].ID)) {
               System.out.println(this.employees[i]);
               
               sc.close();
    }}}


private void retrieveSalary() {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter lowest employee salary: ");
        int LSALARY = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("Enter highest employee salary: ");
        int HSALARY = scan.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < AMOUNT; i++) {
            
        
            if(employees[i].SALARY >= LSALARY & employees[i].SALARY <= HSALARY) {
                   System.out.println(employees[i]);
        
                   scan.close();}}
```

}

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    employeeCase EmployeeData = new employeeCase();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int Select = 0;
    
    do {
        
        displayMenu();
        
        System.out.print("Input your selection from the menu: ");
        Select = sc.nextInt();
        
    switch (Select) {
    
    case 1 :    EmployeeData.loadEmployee();
                break;
                
    case 2 :    EmployeeData.addEmployee();
                break;
                
    case 3 :    EmployeeData.displayEmployee();
                break;
                
    case 4 :    EmployeeData.retrieveSpecific();
                break;
                
    case 5 :    EmployeeData.retrieveSalary();
                break;
                
    case 6 :    System.out.println("Thank you, goodbye!");
                break;
                
    
    default :   System.err.println("Invalid Input");
                break;
    }

    
    } while (Select != 6);
    
    
    
    sc.close();
}
        
        public static void displayMenu() {
            
            System.out.println("                    MENU");
            System.out.println("============================================");
            System.out.println("1: Load employees' data");
            System.out.println("2: Add new employee");
            System.out.println("3: Display all employees");
            System.out.println("4: Retrieve specfic employee data");
            System.out.println("5: Retrieve employee based on salary range");
            System.out.println("6: Exit program");
        }
}}
```

Comment: The main method is static !!

Comment: Take the error message serious: You don't have a `public static void main (String[] args)` method!

Comment: Ok i have edited the main method now but only my retreivesalary won't work with case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method needs to be static. Change `public void main` to `public static void main`.

Comment: once I change it I get an error to remove static

Comment: Main method *must* be static, no exceptions. If the error tells you that it can't be static, that's because you have a dynamic reference in it. You need to fix that by removing the dynamic reference, not by making the method dynamic. Examples of dynamic references include accessing instance variables that aren't static, and calling other methods that aren't static.

Comment: Ok i have edited the main method now but only my retreivesalary won't work with case

Comment: It sounds like I fixed the problem your question was originally asking, and you have a follow up question. In this case, the procedure stackoverflow wants you to follow is to mark my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark, and create a new question if you want to ask something else. It gets confusing when people look at your question if you edit it like that because now your code snippet seems to contain code that doesn't have the problem you're asking about.

Comment: My code still has issues the photo I added of an error still exist, with the same error message

Comment: Ah. I didn't look at the picture at first, because I assumed that it was the same as the snippet. It's also against stackoverflow's rules to put things in photos or behind links, all the details are supposed to be included in text format directly in the question. The error you are getting is from a different class, not the one in the snippet. It's the same fix - go to the file that contains the finalproject class, and define a main method `public static void main(String[] args) {}`.

Comment: I've made all the necessary changes this is the one and only file. My code shows no errors but still getting main method error

Answer (score -1):

Access modifier for main method should be static here you define a non static main method

Replace your main method with
public static void main(String[] args){}

Comment: Ok i have edited the main method now but only my retreivesalary won't work with case